# Android - token from Retrofit Callback response

Tags: java, android, spring-boot

I have a JWT Authentication in Spring Boot application. In the backend, POST method /login return JSON as like

```
{"token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

I have this problem with Android client. I use Retrofit 2.

In interface I have:

```
@POST("/login")
Call<TokenInfo> login(@Body UserCredentials userCredentials);
```

My retrofit Client:

```
package com.findme.my_app_android;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit ourInstance;

    public static Retrofit getInstance(){
        if(ourInstance==null)
            ourInstance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://172.20.10.2:8080")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();

        return ourInstance;
    }
}
```

And in `MainActivity` i use:

```
private void login(UserCredentials userCredentials, final View v){
    Call<TokenInfo> call =  restAPI.login(userCredentials);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<TokenInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TokenInfo> call, Response<TokenInfo> response) {
            //retrofit authentication token save

            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.d("token", response.body().token);
            }

            openDeviceChoiceActivity();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TokenInfo> call, Throwable t) {
            openAlert(v);
        }
    });
}
```

In Call<...> i use `TokenInfo` and `TokenHolder` as below:

```
public class TokenInfo {
    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    public String token;
}
```

or

```
public class TokenHolder {
    private static TokenHolder instance = new TokenHolder();

    private String token = null;
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public static TokenHolder getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, always my `response.body()` is `null`. What is the problem?

Comment: Check `response.errorBody()` you might get some errors

Comment: okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@c58980e

Comment: The issue might be in `request`. Are you sending correct `request`? Check the url and the credentials. Also in your POJO class in `TokenInfo` generate `getter` and `setter` for `token` variable.

Answer (score 0):

check this log:

```
    public void onResponse(Call<TokenInfo> call, Response<TokenInfo> response) {
        Log.d("error", response.errorBody().string())

    }
```

Comment: I get okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@c58980e

Comment: i think you forget to add string()

Comment: I have toString()

Comment: not `toString()` change it with `string()` these are two different functions

Comment: Ok, thanks. I get {"error" : "Authentication failed" }

Answer (score 0):

you should see the

```
response.code()
```

if code is greater than 300 then it is client request error like:
404-> not found
401-> authentication error etc
please let me know the error code